# WSImports specify package name for a class

Tags: java, web-services, java-metro-framework

I have following scenario, I have two packages say com.ws.a and com.ws.b. 
Both the packages having web-services classes. com.ws.a contain class TestServoceA which is having method which returns class TestA. 
I want to pass this generated class to TestServiceB which is in com.ws.b.

But `wsimport` tool generate two different classes for both packages like:
com.ws.a.TestA and
com.ws.b.TestA

I want to generate only one class com.ws.a.TestA as a proxy and use it in both namespaces.
How can I do this? If custom binding can help me please give me example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

wsimport will use JAXB for data binding, follow this documentation to specify custom bindings:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html